# Views Infinite Scroll content doubles up at end of scrolling

Tags: 7, views

I have a View, with Views Infinite Scrolling.  It seems to be working fine, except when I hit the end, the content doubles up.

One interesting thing is they are nodes rendered with Display Suite.  These nodes have an image.  When I hit the bottom and the duplicate nodes display, they are missing the image.  If I go into Firebug, or resize my browser, they display.

How can I fix this behavior?

I'm running Views 3, jQuery 1.8, and Views Infinite Scroll 7.x-1.1+0-dev.

Comment: Have you tried changing the jQuery version or turning off infinite scroll and seeing if there is still a problem with the view?

Comment: Yes.  The Views Infinite Scroll module only seems to work with jQuery 1.8.  Since this is a infinite scroll issue, there wasn't a problem before installing this module.  The default views pager was fine before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going through the code, I see it is because they don't handle the Responsive Grid Views extension, which I am using.  I just hid the duplicate items with CSS for now, and I'll go back and submit a patch to the maintainer later.